# Wizard categorizing in Eclipse plug-in development

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am creating an Eclipse plug-in . and create two wizards for creating project and file and put under a catogory event. When I run the plug-in these two comes under other. I need to be there

```
new -> eventproject and new -> eventfile
```

and eventproject wizard should list under Project catogory

```
new -> project -> eventproject
```

and file should list under file catogory

```
new -> file -> eventfile
```

I am adding my plugin.xml file with this

```
  <plugin>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.newWizards">
          <category
            id="event"
            name="Event">
          </category>

      <wizard
        name="EventFile"
        icon="icons/sample.gif"
        category="event"
        class="plugin.newfile.wizards.NewFile"
        id="plugin.newfile.wizards.NewFile">
  </wizard>
   </extension>
  <extension
        point="org.eclipse.ui.newWizards">
  <category
        id="event"
        name="Event">
  </category>
  <wizard
        category="event"
        class="eventjplugin.wizard.ProjectNewWizard"
        finalPerspective="eventjplugin.perspectives"
        icon="icons/sample.gif"
        id="eventjplugin.wizard.new.event"
        name="EventProject">
  </wizard>
  </extension>
```

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question? Does your wizard appear in the wrong category or in no category at all? The categories you name in the beginning of your question do not match with the ones in your plugin.xml

Comment: There is no `File` category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. There is no file category but there is Project category so I change my plugin.xml as follows

```
<plugin>
 <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.newWizards">
      <category
        id="event"
        name="Event">
      </category>

  <wizard
    name="EventFile"
    icon="icons/sample.gif"
    category="event"
    class="plugin.newfile.wizards.NewFile"
    id="plugin.newfile.wizards.NewFile">
 </wizard>
   </extension>
  <extension
    point="org.eclipse.ui.newWizards">
  <category
      id="event"
      name="Event">
  </category>
  <wizard
    category="event"
    class="eventjplugin.wizard.ProjectNewWizard"
    finalPerspective="eventjplugin.perspectives"
    icon="icons/sample.gif"
    id="eventjplugin.wizard.new.event"
    project ="true"
    name="EventProject">
  </wizard>
  </extension>
```